# How do I send my soldiers out on missions?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

At Mother Base, my soldiers are sayng: "I'll help you get resources Boss". I know from Peace Walker you can send out other soldiers on missions. How do you do that in The Phantom Pain?

Comment: Sometimes the soldiers actually do also say "Send me on a mission, Boss!" or similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For how to send soldiers on dispatch missions, I refer you to what should utimately be your first point of call: **The Game Manual**

> **Dispatch Missions**
>
> With the exception of Snake, Diamond Dogs staff can be sent out on missions.
>   Open "COMBAT DEPLOYMENT" from the "MISSIONS" tab. After selecting a mission from the list, choose the unit's formation.
>   Once a set period of time has passed, the mission results will be displayed. If the mission is successful, you'll receive a reward.
>
> - Be aware that staff sent on missions may be hospitalized or killed, and vehicles may be destroyed.
> - You cannot personally control units you dispatch.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that dispatching isn't an option until you have developed your combat unit in mother base.